# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native, android-build

I have developed Android application which.I had a look online and tried everything I can, still am having issues with Gradle Build, it fails with following errors.

In the project structure 
Gradle version - 4.8
Android plugin version - 3.1.3

please note this is a react native project

Any suggestions on how to fix this will be very very helpful.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:246)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:136)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:201)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:192)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:114)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
    ... 47 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 29s
198 actionable tasks: 184 executed, 14 up-to-date
```

build.gradle

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 18
    targetSdkVersion = 27    
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

dependencies

```
    dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-localization')
    compile project(':realm')
    compile project(':react-native-keychain')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-sensitive-info')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    //compile project(':react-native-secure-key-store')
}
```

gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.enableAapt2=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=xxxx
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=xxx
```

react native - package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
"create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"hex-to-binary": "^1.0.1",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-native": "~0.55.4",
"react-native-build-config": "github:ismaeldcom/react-native-build-config",
"react-native-device-info": "^2.1.3",
"react-native-floating-labels": "^1.1.9",
"react-native-fs": "^2.12.1",
"react-native-keychain": "^3.1.3",
"react-native-localization": "^2.1.2",
"react-native-looped-carousel": "^0.1.13",
"react-native-material-kit": "^0.5.1",
"react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.8",
"react-native-pin-view": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.2.2",
"react-native-sensitive-info": "^5.2.6",
"react-native-vector-icons": "6.5.0",
"react-navigation": "^2.1.0",
"realm": "3.0.0",
"utf8": "^3.0.0"
```

}

After changing the version number of react-native-device-info to 2.1.2 I have the following error

```
> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-build-config
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-material-kit
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed:
com.android.build.threadPoolSize
The com.android.build.threadPoolSize property has no effect


WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Configure project :realm
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :react-native-device-info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\src\main\java\com\learnium\RNDeviceInfo\RNDeviceModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-fs:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules\react-native-fs\android\src\main\java\com\rnfs\RNFSManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-keychain:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules\react-native-keychain\android\src\main\java\com\oblador\keychain\DeviceAvailability.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-localization:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules\react-native-localization\android\src\main\java\com\babisoft\ReactNativeLocalization\ReactNativeLocalization.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :realm:forwardDebugPort
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
===========================================================================
WARNING: Failed to automatically forward port 8083.
In order to use Realm in Chrome debugging mode, port 8083 must be forwarded
from localhost to the device or emulator being used to run the application.
You may need to add the appropriate flags to the command that failed:
    adb forward tcp:8083 tcp:8083
===========================================================================


> Task :realm:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules\realm\android\src\main\java\io\realm\react\RealmReactModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules (63ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules (51ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: Writing bundle output to: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 26 asset files
bundle: Done copying assets

> Task :react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\src\main\java\com\learnium\RNDeviceInfo\RNDeviceModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-fs:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules\react-native-fs\android\src\main\java\com\rnfs\RNFSManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-keychain:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules\react-native-keychain\android\src\main\java\com\oblador\keychain\DeviceAvailability.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-sensitive-info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Warning: The rule `-keep public class *extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation {
  *;
}` uses extends but actually matches implements.
C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.

> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 19s
```

After changes suggested this is the error log

```
> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-build-config
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-material-kit
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed:
com.android.build.threadPoolSize
The com.android.build.threadPoolSize property has no effect


WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Configure project :realm
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules (47ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\node_modules (57ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: Writing bundle output to: C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 26 asset files
bundle: Done copying assets
C:\Development\Dopay-Retail-ReactNative\retail-native-app\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.

> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the react-native-device-info version that you are using.

Firstly unlink and uninstall the current version of react-native-device-info and then,

Just run this command in terminal :

`npm install react-native-device-info@2.1.2`

and then run `react-native link react-native-device-info`

**For more information**: Checkout this thread

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294

Comment: Hi Harshit thank you for respondimg will try this and let you know

Comment: @BRDroid did you try it?

Comment: Hello @Harshit I tried it but still have error, let me update the log at the bottom of the main question,

Comment: disable android x implementation and jetifier

Comment: android.enableAapt2=false
android.enableJetifier=false
this is what you want me to change it to?

Comment: That did not work because `compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 18
    targetSdkVersion = 27  ` and ` compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"`

Comment: also disable android x

Comment: change targetsdkversion to 28

Comment: everytime before running react native run android command, clean the gradle mandatory

Comment: apologies i missed out on a line, this is how it is now. `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.enableAapt2=true
android.enableJetifier=false
android.useAndroidX=false` 
changed targetSdkVersion = 28 
just did the build still has errors. let me update the log in the question,